# node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/lib/jwthelper.service.d.ts has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am facing an issue as mentioned in the title. When I am doing npm start then its shows an attached SS error to me. I am stuck in the deployment process.

Here, are my package.json

```
{
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "^11.2.5",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.1.2",
    "@coreui/angular": "^2.11.2",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.16",
    "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.3.1",
    "@coreui/icons": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "@coreui/icons-angular": "1.0.0-alpha.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/quill": "^1.3.10",
    "abi-decoder": "^2.4.0",
    "alpinejs": "^2.8.2",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^5.0.4",
    "angularx-qrcode": "^11.0.0",
    "angularx-social-login": "^3.5.7",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "ethers": "^5.6.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "firebase": "^8.0",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.5.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fontawesome-4.7": "^4.7.0",
    "ganache": "^7.0.4",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "lazysizes": "^5.3.2",
    "micromodal": "^0.4.6",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.4",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-captcha": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^2.1.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.1.1",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^14.3.0",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "quill-blot-formatter": "^1.0.5",
    "quill-emoji": "^0.2.0",
    "quill-image-resize-module": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.6",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.5.5",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "swiper": "^8.0.7",
    "truffle-contract": "^4.0.31",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.17",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "underscore": "^1.13.1",
    "uninstall": "0.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "web3": "^1.7.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
}
```

[image]

I have tried install other version of Angular and nodejs. But still nothing happen. Guys, please help me to resolve this issue.

```
Angular CLI version is 11.2.19. 
Node version is 14.18.1
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: could be a problem with your angular version. you are using angular 11 and in the @auth0/angular-jwt package is angular 12 used